# Lines over a filled contour in a loop

Tags: r

I computed a loop where I plot Lines over a  filled.contour with lines like this :

```
filled.contour(LON,LAT,FINAL,plot.axes={lines(lontraj,lattraj, 
               type="o",col="blue",cex=1,pch=16, bg=" red")})
```

where *lontraj* and *lattraj* and *final* change at every loop.

The filled contour works OK and it's added at every loop but the lines I have are only from the last loop. It doesn't add it:

[image]
Can someone help me?